# I want to add dynamic bootstrap bg class on a div which is in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-4

I am fetching data from a table called department, which is in admin dashboard and dynamic. Now I want to add classes of BS4 like "success", "primary" and so on, on my div. The problem is that it is in a loop so it is printing the same class every time. How to add dynamic?

```
<div class="row mt-2">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.data)
{

   var department__url = Url.Action("Some Data", new { Some Data= item.Some Data});


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">

             <a href="Some Data" class="card-box noradius noborder bg-secondary">
                    <i class="fa fa-money float-right text-white"></i>
                    <h6 class="text-white text-uppercase m-b-20">Some Data</h6>
                    <h6 class="m-b-20 text-white">
                        <label class="label bg-primary">
                            <span class="counter">Some Data</span> New
                        </label>
                        <label class="label bg-warning">
                            <span class="counter">some data </span> Some Data
                        </label>
                        <label class="label bg-success">
                            <span class="counter">Some Data</span> Done
                        </label>
                    </h6>
                </a>

            </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any distinct value in the item that decides what bootstrap class is. Like for example is 'Some Data' is 1, then apply bg-success. If 'Some Data' is 2, apply bg-warning. If there is, you an probably write something like `"@(Somedata = 1 ? "bg-success": "")` in the class label.

Comment: no i have all data in same loop ,only thing is unique is there id

Comment: you kinda don't get my point. I will write an answer and explain better.

Comment: okay thanks it will help me

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment. I was asking if there is a distinct data in your model that decided the bg-colour. Lets say for example, you have a model like this

```
public class SomeModel
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string SomeData {get; set;}
}
```

and in your view, you are returning a list of lets say 4 items like this...

```
var result = IEnumerable<SomeModel>
{
  new SomeModel{SomeData = "Important Stuff"},
  new SomeModel{SomeData = "Important Stuff"},
  new SomeModel{SomeData = "Not Important Stuff"}
  new SomeModel{SomeData = "Important Stuff"}
}
```

If in the View you want the 'Important stuff' to have `bg-danger` and the 'not important stuff' to have a `bg-warning`, you can put this in the class of the label tag

```
"@(Somedata == "Important Stuff" ? "bg-danger": "bg-warning")
```

If this is not the case for you and you just want any `bg-colour`, you can have a string array with the classes you want and just loop over that. However, you have to make sure the size of the array is the same as the lenght of your list. Either that or circle back to the top of the array when the class in the last index is rendered. Sounds dirty but i cannot think of anything else to achieve that.